# Declaration or statement expected

Tags: discord.js

I have

> "declaration or statement expected"

error, anyone knows why?

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'profil',
    description: 'Informacje o użytkowniku',
    execute(message, args) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        .setTitle('Informacje o użytkowniku')
        .addField('Nazwa użytkownika', message.author.username, true)
        .addField('Obecny Serwer', message.guild.name, true)
        .setColor(0xF1C40F)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
        message.channel.send(embed)),
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the full error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
```

should not have a semicolon at the end, since you're accessing its methods directly.

Additionally, you might want to first instantiate the embed as variable then send it separately:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Informacje o użytkowniku')
    .addField('Nazwa użytkownika', message.author.username, true)
    .addField('Obecny Serwer', message.guild.name, true)
    .setColor(0xF1C40F)
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL());

message.channel.send(embed);
```